# Windows 10: ERROR_NOT_FOUND when opening a virtual serial port even though it exists?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, serial-port, tcomport

Our Delphi Win32 application has been successfully pairing Bluetooth devices (using the Windows Bluetooth API) with the computer and using the resulting serial port.  After installing Windows 10, the virtual serial port resulting from the pairing cannot be opened.  Our application can see the new com port but when it tries to open it, error 1168 (ERROR_NOT_FOUND) occurs.

I can see the com port has been created in Windows as well (associated with the same device serial number I am trying to connect to).  The com port is the same as what my application has been trying to open.

Tried exiting my application and using a trusted terminal program (to guarantee that the port will be available).  it can't open the port either.

It makes me wonder whether Windows 10 is doing some new, aggressive power saving in respect to the Bluetooth radio.

Upgraded a laptop from Win 7 to Win 10; same result.  that's both computers upgraded to Win10 showing the same problem.

Made a C# app with Visual studio 2013; same result.

Any ideas why I would get error 1168 when trying to open the port?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Talking with Microsoft about this.  We think it's a problem with the Bluetooth stack in windows 10.  Not solved and no workaround.

Comment: Level 2 support blames computer manufacturers for this problem.  It's surprising that all the computers we tried show this problem...several different models and manufacturers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Until Microsoft fixes this I'll have to use a Win 7 VM.

Comment: We're migrating to RFCOMM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been told Windows 10 has an all-new Bluetooth stack.

This new stack only supports SPP 1.2.  We needed 1.1 supported.

Migrating to RFCOMM.